Freeze Function of PYTH Token on Solana
Does the PYTH token on Solana ever have a Freeze Authority account to support the freeze function? According to SolanaFM, the Freeze Authority of PYTH is empty and according to SolanaBeach, the Freeze Authority is the System Program (11111111111111111111111111111111). So does it mean PYTH has never had a Freeze Authority account so it does not support the freeze function?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
